# How to still return psql query if value in row is null (value also linked to other row)

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I have two tables in postgres db. Companies and bootcampers. Companies.company_id is primary key to bootcampers.company_id foreign key.

Trying to select all rows from bootcampers and company_id and company_name from companies based on company_id.  Some bootcampers will not have a company_id yet. How can i change this psql query to say please return all fields but if company_id is blank, return everything else anyway.  Is there a 'null is ok' thing i need to use?

```
SELECT uid,
    email,
    photourl,
    first_name,
    surname,
    aboutme,
    job_title,
    company_name,
    salary,
    start_date,
    previous_roles,
    cohort_num,
    region,
    job_satisfaction,
    new_job,
    bootcampers.twitter,
    github,
    portfolio,
    bootcampers.linkedin 
FROM companies 
  INNER JOIN bootcampers ON bootcampers.company_id = companies.company_id 
WHERE first_name ILIKE '%' || $1 || '%'
```

Comment: you want a `left join`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want everything from Bootcampers you need a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT uid,
    email,
    photourl,
    first_name,
    surname,
    aboutme,
    job_title,
    company_name,
    salary,
    start_date,
    previous_roles,
    cohort_num,
    region,
    job_satisfaction,
    new_job,
    bootcampers.twitter,
    github,
    portfolio,
    bootcampers.linkedin 
FROM companies 
  RIGHT JOIN bootcampers ON bootcampers.company_id = companies.company_id 
WHERE first_name ILIKE '%' || $1 || '%'
```

Be careful if you want to add a filter on a column from the companies table as that could negate your `RIGHT JOIN` and make it work like an `INNER` again.